# Magento 2 Installation issues

Tags: magento2

I installed Magento 2 on one of the domain name. The installation worked properly and shows me the Success page. However, when I access the website and admin panel it shows distorted. Here is the website wholesaleadda dot com

If anybody faced such issues OR point me in the right direction, it will be helpful.

Comment: Please explain the issue, or use screenshots, instead of posting your URL, so that the question will be useful for others too.

Comment: Looks like you server cannot access to static files. Can you verify access?

Comment: Here is the screen shot http://snag.gy/ZPZLx.jpg which shows the distorted website. In regards to static files, I see that the permissions and ownership is correct. By static files, do you mean the static directory under pub ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your permissions are ok, you should deploy static contents doing:

`php [magento2 root]/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [locale]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did use the command provided. However, it still shows the same. After executing the command it did work properly and did not show any errors.

Comment: I just followed your link and looking with chrome it's clear that the error is around server permissions and/or apache/nginx misconfiguration the response header is 403 Forbidden. Try to follow the path in your server  and verify file(s) permission.  And check with which user are you running cronjobs and/or deploy files.

Comment: Thanks. I cleared the cache and it started working. Thank you very much for your steps.

Comment: Cool! BTW take a look to `var/genaration`, `var/di` and `var/view_preprocessed` permissions too, any permissions error there would be more complex to find. :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the permissions are correct. Magento 2 has a complete different structure than the previous versions. Out of curiosity, I wanted to know how come the website did not work properly after installing Magento 2 on the domain ? When installation completed, it did not show any errors though.

Comment: Yes it's absolutely different, i'm actually refactoring all our automated deploy process to fit these kind of code/content generation. i'm pretty sure that every minimal deploy will be incremented from a few seconds to a couple of minutes... but don't worry we are all "newbies" with M2 :)